# Return response in the new window

Tags: symfony, response, target

How can i return response object in new window ? I mean, i need to response html page but in the new window like a target blank.

```
    $response = new Response($html);
    $response->setStatusCode(200); 
    return $response;
```

Above code return the html page but in the same tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symfony doesn't handle this.  This is handled by client side functionality (target).  The best thing to do is to make the trigger for your action open in a new window.  So if your trigger is a link, you can do something like:

```
<a href="{{ path('yourRoute') }}" target="_blank">Open in new window</a>
```